# Win8: Hiding Toast Notifications

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, toast

I have been working with toast notifications for a while now, and I have a particular edge case that I can't seem to resolve.  If I schedule a toast, let's say for one hour after I close the associated app, it appears one hour later, which is great.  When I click on the notification itself, it will also launch my app, which is also great.

However, if I see the notification, and click on the app tile, the application launches, but the notification will remain until I click on it, or hit its close button.  I feel that there should be a way for me to get my hands on this active notification (say by ID) and then manually dismiss it, since the user has opened the app, etc.  Is there a way to do such a thing, or am I just out of luck?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`toastNotifier.hide`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications.toastnotifier.hide.aspx) method. As notification I'd pass new `Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotification` object with the same id as currently visible toast. Alternatively you could use [`removeFromSchedule`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications.toastnotifier.removefromschedule.aspx) method.

Comment: If the toast is active (i.e. visible), then it isn't in the schedule.  Also, sending up a new toast will put another one on the screen.

Comment: so notifier.getScheduledToastNotifications() doesn't return it?

Comment: No.  When the scheduled time elapses, the toast is displayed, and is therefore no longer scheduled.  It goes from the schedule to the screen.  Try it yourself and see.